# Save cleaned up log file with original headers on PowerShell

Tags: powershell

It is necessary to delete lines with data slice from the file with logs. my solution looks like this:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\User\Desktop\Performance_.log | 
    Select-String -Pattern '(202007|202008|202009)' | 
        %{$_.ToString()} | 
            Out-File C:\Users\User\Desktop\out.log
```

But the file is saved without headers. Please tell me how to resave the file with headers. I cannot implement it on the PS. I don't know the language. Thank you very much!

Comment: If it is only the first line you want to save you can use `Select-Object -First 1` to omit everything than the first line.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$header = Get-Content 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Performance_.log' -First 1
$content = Get-Content C:\Users\User\Desktop\Performance_.log | Select-String -Pattern '(202007|202008|202009)' | % {$_.ToString()}

#Output to file
$header | Out-File C:\Users\User\Desktop\out.log
$content | Out-File C:\Users\User\Desktop\out.log -append
```

I'm getting the content twice, putting into two variables. Then we use out-file to create a file with the header, and then we do out-file again but this time with the `-append` flag set so that the header is not overwritten.

---

If you're working with a CSV, I would not use the above method. I would instead use import-csv. It's much easier to handle, and more flexible a csv-object than a string in my opinion.

```
$content = import-csv 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Performance_.log' | where-object {$_.ExampleFirstColumn -match '(202007|202008|202009)'}
$content | Export-csv "C:\Users\User\Desktop\out.log" -NoTypeInformation
```

Just replace the "ExampleFirstColumn" text in the code above with the name of the header.